# Search partial match strings from multiple table in mysql query (very complex query)

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables - `business`, `products` and `subproducts`.

The table structure is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f3342/1 here.

I need to pass in a `string` to search. It has to search all the three tables(all columns) and return `id` from the `business` table. `bid` is the `business id (id)` for `products` table and `pid` is the `product id (id)` for `sub_products` table.

Then I need to order the results in the order of table like  `business`,`products` then `subproducts`.

How can I do all this?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could give a example view of what exactly you want, it would help us to answer the question and understand why you need it to be one query.

Comment: It is for search page. If user searches by a string then it should search firstly from business table then products table then sub-products table. And return the corresponding business from the business table. No need that it should be from in a single query but query should be optimized to reduce execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if it doesn't have to be just one query

```
SELECT id 
FROM business 
WHERE Concat(name, '', category, '', s_desc, '' , f_desc, '', address1, '', views) like '%test%'
```

This will search for the specified columns in the `business` table that contains 'test' string. You can extend this query to include all the relevant columns as well as different tables you want to search. Just pass your search string from php into that query and it will return the id.

*P.S. don't pass your input directly into your query (process and escape it first), as it will be open to sql injection.*

I hope this helps.